# Google Charts API - Overlapping X axis labels

Tags: google-visualization

I have a chart generated from Google Charts that can be found here: [Chart generate by Google Charts API](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chd=s%3aAAA9A&chl=Once%7C2-3%20times%7C4-5%20times%7C6-10%20times%7C%3E10%20times&chtt=Visits%20per%20Month&cht=bvs&chs=300x200&chxr=0,0,1).  As you can see the x axis labels are being overlapped.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs under [Bar Width and Spacing (chbh)](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#chbh). There's this snippet:

> `a` - space_between_bars and space_between_groups are given in
>   absolute units (or default absolute values, if not specified). Bars
>   will be resized so that all bars will fit in the chart.

So just add `chbh=a` to the options. Here's [the example](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chd=s%3aAAA9A&chl=Once%7C2-3%20times%7C4-5%20times%7C6-10%20times%7C%3E10%20times&chtt=Visits%20per%20Month&cht=bvs&chs=300x200&chxr=0,0,1&chbh=a) with this option added.